# Read file in node.js while it is opened for writing by another software

Tags: node.js, stream

Situation:
1. One app (not node.js) writes data to some file, size is unknown
2. Node.js should pipe contents of that file until it is opened for writing by the first app.

Is it possible?

Comment: You just described the concept of a socket. What is your specific problem? Have you written any code you are stuck with?

Comment: the file is a text file or something a byte stream?

Answer (score 5):

You have some solution.

**writeStream.js** is a simple test class to write in the file as demo

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fd = fs.openSync('./openedFile.txt', 'w+')
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(null, {
  fd,
  encoding: 'utf8'
})
process.stdin.pipe(stream)
```

**readStream polling**: this is simple, the read stream is always closed when it reaches the end of file (EOF) and a 'end' event is fired. So you can't keep an open fd to a file if you read it all. (in this example I don't manage if the stream is still open because it could not have read all the file)

```
const fs = require('fs')
let streamed = 0
function readFd() {
  const fd = fs.openSync('./openedFile.txt', 'r')
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(null, {
    fd,
    encoding: 'utf8',
    start: streamed
  })
  stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    streamed += chunk.length;
  })
  stream.pipe(process.stdout)
}

setInterval(readFd, 1000)
```

**readStream via tail** (tail command will poll for you)

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('tail', ['-f', 'openedFile.txt']);
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: I think this might help me with my problem, hope you don't mind me asking a few question. process.stdout, is that data of the file being read? would you be able to emit that using socket.io-client? if yes, how would I go about doing that? placing the io.emit() inside the pipe() doesn't seem to be the proper way

Comment: Could you open a new question adding your code? I'm not a socket.io user and a starting code would help me to give it a try

Comment: Sorry I can't post questions anymore. But if it helps I'll explain it in more details here. I'm trying to send an audio file that's still being written (using https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16) to an API using socket.io-client (similar to this docu https://docs.marsview.ai/realtime-speech-analytics-api/initiate-stream). I was wondering if I could use your code to read what's being written and send it to the API